# magento 1.9.x Modman vs modgit

Tags: magento-1.9, git, deploy, modman

I'm looking for best practice in order to manage magento submodules, my plan was to use modman but I've heard about modgit. 
Is there any benchmark modman vs modgit? 
Advantages / disadvantages or each one, I don't know which one I should use. Any recommendations ?